# Passing data on button click from five activities to one activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, message

This is for a game i am trying. First(1st activity) to Fith level(5th activity) have questions with multiple choice. The user is taken to the next level irrespective of what his answer is. At the end of the fifth level, he is told that 1) You have cleared all OR IF ONE OR MORE ARE WRONG 2) You have made a mistake.

i.e he is notified of his result at the end of five levels.(he is not told which question is incorrect just that he has made a mistake)

Can somebody help me with the codes?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is to store the result of each activity in a Sharedpreference and retrieve this at the end of the game.

Comment: SQLite is also an option. Infect a better option.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem: i think using SQLite will be an overkill for this...i am not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to get you started with **SharedPreferences**

This is how you store in SharedPref, you can use it in each level to store the result:

```
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
sharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();         
prefeditor.putBoolean("level1",YOUR_BOOL_VALUE);          
prefeditor.commit();
```

Similarly you use `getBoolean` to retrieve the values which you have stored (in the last activity)!

Comment: Only that putBoolean() won't accept two String arguments, please edit the answer.

Comment: @Alborz: all five activities sends its data to 6th one which verifies them with an if statement. Like that?

Comment: @user1506106, yes, at the end of each activity you calculate the result and store it. At the last level you check to see that all the stored results are TRUE.